# Utility to Upload CSV into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

Is there any utility available to Import the table data from CSV file.

Since I have huge no of tables and rows.Writing COPY FROM sql will take a time,so in need of any utility or another approaches

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really should use [`copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

(
  echo 'copy table_name from stdin (format csv);'
  cat table_name.csv || exit 1
  echo '\.'
) | psql database_name
```

You don't need to change your big files in any way. You may need to tweak some copy options (`delimiter`, `quote` etc.).

Comment: Agree, `COPY` operator's built in CSV support is very powerfull.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

http://csvloader.sourceforge.net/